orthogonality in the hyerbolic geometry
Consider the half-plane model$ ~\mathbb{H}^2$  hyperbolic plane
$\mathcal{P}:=i ,~\mathcal{T}:=10+i \text{ and } \mathcal{g}:=\{z\in \mathbb{H}^2:Re(z)=0\}$
Show that the straight lines$~\mathcal{PT}$ and $\mathcal{g}$ do $\mathbf{not}$ intersect perpendicularly ($\mathcal{PT}\perp \mathcal{g}$). Check whether there is a point on the straight line g call it $\mathcal{~C}$ such that, $~\Delta_\mathcal{PTC}$ is an isosceles triangle with base $\mathcal{\overline{PT}~}$. $$Note:$$
$d_\mathbb{H}^2(z,w)=d_\mathbb{H}^2(u,v)\iff r(z,w)^2 = r(u,v)^2$ with
$r(z,w)^2 :=\frac{|z-w|}{|z-\overline{w}|} $
For the first part: If I am correct, orthogonality in the hyerbolic sense is exactly the same as orthogonality in the Euclidean sense.
For the second part i tried to use the follwing $d_\mathbb{H}^2(z,w)=d_\mathbb{H}^2(u,v)\iff r(z,w)^2= r(u,v)^2$ , but unfortunately I was not able to get the result I know by pluging the function in wolfram alpha :/
$$\frac{\left|ix-i\right|}{\left|ix+i\right|}=\frac{\left|ix-10-i\right|}{\left|ix-10+i\right|}$$ trying to solve for x, if im not wrong is the right approach
I would appreciate help :)

"hyerbolic sense is exactly the same as orthogonality in the Euclidean sense."  Yes, more generally, we say this model is "conformal", preserving angles.

$x=0$ should be the only solution.

What does “do not cut vertically” mean?

I have edited it :)

A bit too many points here... Are points $\mathcal{A,B}$ the same as $\mathcal{P,T}$?

yes. thanks for drawing my attention to it :)
